# Is this yellow flower I saw in Patagonia Calceolaria Uniflora?

Tags: identification, flowers

I've made this picture:

[image: flower]

and I like to know what this flower is called. The picture was taken in Patagonia, Chile. I assume it could be *Calceolaria Uniflora*, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Bingo, I think you've got it!  It looks exactly like Calceolaria Uniflora.

Here are [some images](https://www.google.com/search?q=Calceolaria%20Uniflora&client=firefox-a&hs=DYq&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=np&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=GOVaU677HoTwyQHOsIGgDw&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1291&bih=596) to confirm it.